# Throttle a signal whilst the application is not active

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'd like to ensure a `RACSignal` only sends events while the application is active. Additional `next` events send in the background should be dropped, but, if at least one occurs, the latest should be sent when the application enters the foreground.

I know that I can use `UIApplicationState` to determine the current state, and `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` to determine when the application enters the foreground. I can't use `-sample:` because all events that occur in the foreground should be sent immediately.

The use case is: an external device connects to and communicates with the application. Based on the information provided by this device, network requests will be made - but they should not be made in the background, and only the latest data is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This was really fun to figure out so I'm just going to jump straight to the code and then explain why it does what it does.

```
RACSignal * backgroundSignal = [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter rac_addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
RACSignal * foregroundSignal = [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter rac_addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
[[[[[backgroundSignal mapReplace:@NO] merge:
 [[foregroundSignal mapReplace:@YES] delay:0.1]] startWith:@YES] 
 map:^RACStream *(NSNumber * value) {
    if (value.boolValue)
    {
        return [[RACSignal interval:1 onScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler]] mapReplace:@"Foreground"];
    }
    return [[[RACSignal interval:10 onScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler]] mapReplace:@"Background"] sample:foregroundSignal];
 }].switchToLatest subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"%@", x);
}];
```

So we're using both the foreground and background signals as boolean flags for whether or not we're in the foreground, pretty vanilla stuff here.

To avoid the signal switching immediately (and our latest signal from the background being lost), we're delaying the foreground signal by 0.1 seconds. You can tune this value to taste, but it's a necessary evil.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the cleanest way to do it:

```
RACSignal * backgroundSignal = [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter rac_addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
RACSignal * foregroundSignal = [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter rac_addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

// This is the signal you are expecting events from. Note the replayLast operator will always remember the last value
RACSignal * eventSignal = [[RACSignal never] replayLast];

// These signals map the background and foreground signals so on the event of going into the foreground the eventsSignal will be sent and nothing if in the background

RACSignal * backgroundReplaceSignal = [backgroundSignal flattenMap:^RACStream* (id: NSObject){ return [RACSignal never]}];
RACSignal * foregroundReplaceSignal = [foregroundSignal flattenMap:^RACStream* (id: NSObject){ return eventSignal}];


// We then simply have to merge and swithchToLatest which will result in us being subscribed to our events signal when in the foreground and an empty signal in the background
[[[RACSignal merge: @[backgroundReplaceSignal,foregroundReplaceSignal]] switchToLatest] subscribeNext:^(id: NSObject) {
    /*You will only get results from the events signal if your app is in the foreground and when it comes into the foreground you will
    get the last evvents signal send because for the replayLast
    */
}];
```

Comment: Did you actually test that code?  I changed the `never` calls to use `interval:onScheduler:` and the code definitely does not work the way the question wants.

Comment: So I tested it in swift and it worked fine and then just ported it over to obj-c. I will do a quick Obj-C test and update it soon. Sorry about that.